# How to run multiple Groovy unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, groovy, tdd

I want to keep my groovy source files in their own directory, with the tests being in a separate directory.

I have the directory structure as follows:

```
.
├── build
│   └── Messenger.class
├── build.xml
├── ivy.xml
├── lib
├── src
│   └── com
│       └── myapp
│           └── Messenger.groovy
└── test
    └── unit
        ├── AnotherTest.groovy
        └── MessengerTest.groovy
```

I can successfully run one test by using the `groovy` command and specifying the class path for the units under test using `-cp` to point to `build/` but how do I run all the tests in the directory?

Comment: How are you running these tests? In Grails, a `test-app` usually runs all the tests unless you explicitly limit them so I assume you are using a non-standard way?

Comment: This isn't a Grails app.

Comment: Then remove the grails tag

Comment: I have it there because I'm using the directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

Tou can run  all unit test with command:

> grails test-app unit:

If you have unit, integration, functional... tests you can run all tests with command:

> grails test-app

Comment: This isn't a Grails app, I'm just mimicking the directory structure a bit.

Comment: I'm not using an IDE, that's why I was running the tests using the `groovy` command.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to groovy, but I wrote my own test runner and put it in root directory of my project. Source code:

```
import groovy.util.GroovyTestSuite
import junit.textui.TestRunner
import junit.framework.TestResult
import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES


public class MyTestRunner {
    public static ArrayList getTestFilesPaths(String test_dir) {
        // gets list of absolute test file paths
        ArrayList testFilesPaths = new ArrayList();

        new File(test_dir).eachFileRecurse(FILES) {
            if(it.name.endsWith(".groovy")) {
                testFilesPaths.add(it.absolutePath)
            }
        }

        return testFilesPaths;
    }

    public static GroovyTestSuite getTestSuite(ArrayList testFilesPaths) {
        // creates test suite using absolute test file paths
        GroovyTestSuite suite = new GroovyTestSuite();
        testFilesPaths.each {
            suite.addTestSuite(suite.compile(it));
        }
        return suite;
    }

    public static void runTests(GroovyTestSuite suite) {
        // runs test in test suite
        TestResult result = TestRunner.run(suite);
        // if tests fail return exit code non equal to 0 indicating that
        // tests fail it helps if one of your build step is to test files
        if (!result.wasSuccessful()) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}

ArrayList testFilesPaths = MyTestRunner.getTestFilesPaths("tests");
GroovyTestSuite suite = MyTestRunner.getTestSuite(testFilesPaths);
MyTestRunner.runTests(suite)
```

if you try to use this be aware that if it fails it is most likely that `getTestFilesPaths` is not working properly.

**My directory structure**

```
.
├── test_runner.groovy
├── src
│   └── ...
└── tests
    └── Test1.groovy
    └── someDir
        ├── Test2.groovy
        └── Test3.groovy
```

**How to run**
From the same directory where `test_runner.groovy` is run:

```
groovy test_runner.groovy
```